# In MVC Folder name and view name are same,but first it enters into view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a mvc project my url is `hostname/xxxx` and i have folder name called `xxxx`.

If i enter this url `hostname/xxxx` means it directly go to my folder but i want it go to my code controller

Comment: If you have an MVC project that you didn't alter, that should be the case. However, if you change your **routing** setup, this can be the case. The key part here is check how your **routing** is done.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? Is it IIS Express? Or real IIS on a server?

Comment: @Flater: can you please send me the routing??

Comment: Seriously, no. I went to the effort of highlighting the important word that you can use to google this; which is more than others usually offer if you do not post your own efforts.

Comment: @Flater: I said the route url path, But i dont know to get inside the code controller directly..

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your routing file to tell it to use the route rather than browse the directory

```
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

This means that if you have a route of myHost/myFolder and a file of myHost/myFolder/myFile.ext, then the URL myHost/myFolder will be handled by MVC routing and the URL myHost/myFolder/myFile.ext will navigate to the file.

Comment: After this, I want to enter into the folder means,what i want to do??

Comment: If you have a file hostname/xxxx/myfile.txt then you can still navigate to it. It's only hostname/xxxx (or any other part which matches a route) that will be handled by MVC routing. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: :Thank you.Your coding work now after how to access that content folder if i give the that file name means it always come to my controller it didn't go to the folder content

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have these in your IIS handler mappings then you need to install mvc on the server

[image]